# Delphi 7 TidHttp.post not sending data to server

Tags: delphi, post, indy

I am using this to post a form:

```
c := tidhttp.Create(self);
p := tstringlist.Create;

p.Add('field=value');

s := c.Post('http://www.test.com/action.php', p);

p.Free;
c.Free;
```

Tried hosting online and tried Xampp, I get the same results, no data received.

The form:

```
<form action="action.php" method="POST" name="test">
<input type="text" name="field"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

There are so many answers suggesting that I am doing it right but the data is not received
Tried `TStringSTream.create(UTF8String('field=value'))` but nothing

Comment: You did not show us an important part !  The code of **action.php** !! 
how can we see what happens inside action.php. 
Are you the owner of **action.php** ?

Comment: I am the owner of action.php, I have also tried on multiple other websites with simple login forms, they either redirected to the login page again or showed a "username/password empty" error. I am completely puzzled too, I don't see anything wrong, it's probably something very silly.

Comment: And now can you show us action.php or not ?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Your HTML webform is configured to submit its data to `http://www.test.com/action.php` (assuming the HTML page resides at `http://www.test.com/`).</strike>

Your Indy code is `Post()`ing its data to `http://www.test.com` instead.  You need to use the correct URL when posting data in code:

```
s := c.Post('http://www.test.com/action.php', p);
```

If I had to guess (and you should never make people guess), when you are `Post()`'ing <strike>to `http://www.test.com`</strike>, you are likely getting redirected <strike>to `http://www.test.com/` (notice the trailing slash)</strike>.  If the redirect uses reply code `303`, or uses `302` and you have the `hoTreat302Like303` option enabled in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property, then `TIdHTTP` wwill send a `GET` instead of a `POST` to the new URL being redirected to.

Comment: Actually it's a mistake, I modified the posted code so my details won't show up and I forgot that one. action.php is part of the original code.

Comment: Please update the question to show the actual HTTP requests that TIdHTTP is sending.  To get that data, you can either 1) use a packet sniffer like Wireshark, 2) use a debugging proxy like Fiddler, or 3) attach one of Indy's `TIdLog....` components to `TIdHTTP`.

Comment: TidLogDebug and Microsoft Network Monitor shows the fields being transmitted.

Comment: Then the problem is likely on the PHP side. Maybe your PHP script is not looking for the data in the right place.

Comment: I have tried using other websites, you know, easy post logins, same results the username and password  are empty fields. Some say the fields are empty and some redirect to the login page again.

Comment: Again, please show the actual HTML and the actual HTTP requests that `TIdHTTP` is sending.  Something is obviously missing, but I can't tell you what that is yet. It would also be useful if you would do the same test in a working webbrowser and show those HTTP requests for comparison.